# Make all array elements equal by multiplying by any number with each array elements

Tags: arrays, c

If an array a[] = {2,3,4,5}
For the first sample case , 2, 3, 4 and 5 can be multiplied by 1800, 1200, 900 & 720 correspondingly। These numbers are
multiples of 2, 3, 4 and 5. And after multiplying all the numbers become same (3600).

If we want to make all the elements equal we can do this 2×1800 = 3600, 3×1200=3600, 4×900=3600, 5×720=3600; And we have to print the equal number 3600. Here the wrong code.

```
 #include <stdio.h>

 bool EqualNumbers(int a[], int n)
 {

 int i, j;
for ( i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    for(j = 0; j<n; j++)
    {


 while (a[i] % a[i]== 0)
        a[i] = a[i] * a[i];
    }


     

    if (a[i] != a[0]) {
        return false;
    }
}


   return true;
 }
int main()
{
int j, m;
scanf("%d", &m);
int a[m];


for(j = 0; j < m; j++)
{
    scanf("%d", &a[j]);
}

int n = sizeof(a) / sizeof(a[0]);


 if (EqualNumbers(a, n))
 {
   for(j = 0; j < m; j++)
  {
    printf("%d", a[j]);
    
  }
  }

return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Please format your code that it's somewhat legible.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because you were (politely) asked to format your code properly and you didn't.